# Sveltekit communication between layout, routes and components

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to move a svelte SPA into Sveltekit.

In my SPA, the communication schema is what I would call a "controller component" which takes care of displaying some components, listen to their events and update the app accordingly. By and large it looks like this REPL:

https://svelte.dev/repl/47bd3f8004624a3c95653b1f1aefd8ee?version=3.46.4

As you can see in this example, the sequence is fairly trivial:
App state 1) App shows CompA and CommonComp
App state 2) CompA triggers the doSomething function just after being mounted
App state 3) App then call commonComp.setTitle and show CompB in place of CompA

In SvelteKit, I struggle to do something similar cause I don't understand how to pass data from a slotted sub component to the Component containing the slot and conversely.
Anyway, this led me to this attempt:

1. I need 2 routes:

   - PageA.svelte for when CompA & CommonComp are displayed
   - PageB.svelte for when CompB & CommonComp are displayed
2. Because CommonComp is always visible in every states, I would think that it should resides in a __layout.svelte file.

...This took me to the draft below with the comments explaining the access problem I encounter.

***/src/routes/__layout.svelte***

```js
<slot />
<CommonComp />
```

***/src/routes/PageA.svelte***

```js
<script>
  import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
  import CompA from "$lib/CompA.svelte";

  function handleDoSomethingFinished() {
    goto("/test/pageB");
  }
</script>

<CompA on:do_something_finished={handleDoSomethingFinished} />
```

***/src/lib/CompA.svelte***

```js
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  onMount(() => {
    setTimeout(() => dispatch("do_something_finished"), 3000);
  });
</script>

<p>Component A</p>
```

***/src/routes/PageB.svelte***

```js
<script>
  import CompB from "$lib/CompB.svelte";

  // How to call CommonComp.setTitle function from here ?
 
</script>

<CompB  />
```

***/src/lib/CompB.svelte***

```js
<p>Component B</p>
```

***/src/lib/CommonComp.svelte***

```js
<script>
  let title = "Common Component";
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  export function setTitle(t) {
    title = t;
    dispatch("title-modified");
  }
</script>

<p>{title}</p>
```

I guess I may have tried to share some stores and check they value into reactive statements to trigger the appropriate actions but when I'm thinking of it, I see a can of worms so I'm missing something here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little complex. According to the Svelte docs on [`export`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-1-export-creates-a-component-prop):

> If you export a const, class or function, it is readonly from outside
> the component. Function expressions are valid props, however.
>
> Readonly props can be accessed as properties on the element, tied to
> the component using bind:this syntax.

Meaning that you would have to create a reference to `CommonComp` using `bind:this` then pass it around in order for the `setTitle` method to be called on it. This would be prop drilling down with the added headache of drilling down from a layout's `slot`. I would not recommend that at all.

One route is to make use of the [`load`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading) facility and [`stuff`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading#output-stuff), by setting a property like, say, `ccTitle` on the `stuff` object from the load function of PageB, then subscribing to the `page` store provided by `$app/stores` inside `CommonComp` to set the title reactively:

```js
$: title = $page.stuff.ccTitle || "Common Component"
```

**however**, because you're setting `stuff` from the `load` function of PageB, it is not very flexible (`load` is executed from the module section *prior* to the page actually loading, so you cannot interact with `stuff` from the actual page script).

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-owjqkb?file=src%2Froutes%2FPageB.svelte&terminal=dev) is a bare bones example of the method above.

In the end, the store route you appear reluctant to go down to would be the simplest and most straightforward option. The `title` store is basic to the extreme:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const title = writable('Common Component');

export default title;
```

So is using the store in `CommonComp`:

```js
<script>
  import title from "$lib/stores/title";
</script>

<p>{$title}</p>
```

And so is setting a new title from PageB:

```js
<script>
  import CompB from "$lib/CompB.svelte";
  import title from "$lib/stores/title";

  $title = "Custom Title";
  // or say you wanted to set it reactively based on a 'foo' variable:
  // $: $title = foo
</script>

<CompB />
```

This is miles simpler & cleaner than the `load` approach mentioned above, as well as a would-be drilling down approach. Stores do *not* need to be complex and are extraordinarily helpful to communicate across pages & components.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-qemt1m?file=src%2Flib%2Fstores%2Ftitle.js&terminal=dev) is a bare bones example using the stores approach.

**Update / edit:**

If you wanted to keep your common component methods encapsulated, you could also use the store method mentioned above, but instead of storing the title, you would store the reference to your `CommonComp` instance, thus providing a means to call `$commonComp.setTitle()` from any page or component that subscribed to the store.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-uhdwg7?file=src%2Froutes%2FPageB.svelte&terminal=dev) is an example using that approach.

Comment: The last Update is a clever approach. I'm surprise to see the need of a reactive statement for the assignment of the component reference to the store here `$: $commonComp = ccRef;` in `__layout.svelte` as I thought stores were already reactive but here it's needed to work properly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This reactive statement is needed because `ccRef` will be null/undefined before the component mounts. An alternative would be to do a simple `$commonComp = ccRef` assignment inside the `onMount` lifecycle function, but this is just simpler ;) And you're welcome!